# What should be the type of a merged object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have

```
export interface Game {
    startingTime?: string;
    minutes?: string;
    finished: boolean;
    homeTeam: string;
    awayTeam: string;
    score?: string;
}    
export class Markets {
    constructor() {
        return {
            '1': '',
            x: '',
            '2': '',
            '1x': '',
            x2: ''
        };
    }
}
```

and my final object I want it to look something like this:

```
const games = [
  {...{ finished: true, homeTeam: 'Santa Rosa', awayTeam: 'Molinos El Pirata', score: '0-3' }, ...new Markets()},
  {...{ finished: false, minutes: '75', homeTeam: 'Chavelines', awayTeam: 'Deportivo Coopsol', score: '1-0' }, ...new Markets()}
];
```

so what should the type of `games` be?
this doesn't make eslint complain, but is it correct?

```
games: Game | Markets[] = [];
```

for me, this would look more correct:

```
games: Game & Markets[] = [];
```

but eslint says:

```
Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'Game & Markets[]'.
  Type 'never[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Game': finished, homeTeam, awayTeamts(2322)
```

Comment: The correct type would be`Array<Game & Markets>`

Comment: I have a feeling that Game & Markets[] should have worked as well :) thank you so much, please add it as an answer instead of comment, so that I can accept it.

Comment: Also, you could use `(Game & Market)[]`

Comment: @ToddSkelton ah, there you go, ok, so that way is possible, but it needs the brackets. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enclose the types in parentheses, so they both apply to the array.

`(Game & Market)[]`

Or use `Array<Game & Markets>` like @lleon suggested.